# Force the user to select one photo in android

Tags: android

In my android application in file `activity_mai.xml` I have for default in `ImageView` set the value of `ic_launcher.png`.

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/viewImage"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="0.05"
  android:contentDescription="@string/content"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
/>
```

I need check that when is executed the upload of image file the image not is ic_launcher and force the user to select one pic existent or taken new photo in his smartphone.

I have tried this method without success, because this check is not performed.

`My code below:`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    if (area.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()
            .equalsIgnoreCase("area")) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "area.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (messageText.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {            
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "message",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         

    } else if (arg0 == btnselectpic) {
        selectImage();
    } else if (arg0 == uploadButton) {

        if (imageview.toString().equals("ic_launcher.png")) {
            messageText.setError("image");
        } else {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                    "Uploading file...", false, false);

            int secondsDelayed = 5;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
        }
```

Thanks in advance

`edit`

```
        if (imageview.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.ic_launcher)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "image",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

`LogCat`

```
09-26 14:11:10.530: 
D/MainActivity.class(9773): 
myDrawable 1 : android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@425dc490


09-26 14:11:10.530: D/MainActivity.class(9773): 
myDrawable 2 : android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@4326f0e0



        Log.d("MainActivity.class", "myDrawable 1 : " + imageview.getDrawable());
        Log.d("MainActivity.class", "myDrawable 2 : "
                + getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

Comment: `imageview` is a imageview object?

Comment: yes is an imageview object

Comment: So what is this? `imageview.toString()`?

Comment: how do you expect this to be true `if(imageview.toString().equals("ic_launcher.png"))`

Comment: I have tried this but not working ... `if (imageview.getDrawable() == null)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the file name of an image inside an imageView with toString(). This is how toString() is described in the API:

- Returns a string containing a concise, human-readable description of this object.

But this means not the file name. If You want to get the fileName from an Image, it is a better solution to set the file name as a tag when setting this image to the view like this:

```
   yourImageView.setTag(yourFileName);
```

To give You a better help, we need to see, where the user chooses an image and where this image is setted to the view. At this place, there must be the name setted as tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try out by this

```
Drawable myDrawable = yourImageView.getDrawable();
```

You can compare it with a drawable resource like

```
if(yourImageView.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)){
    messageText.setError("image");
}
else
{
    // complete your work       
}
```

Comment: thank you, but the upolad is started ... please read my edit in firts question

Comment: Is it not comparing your imageview image with launcher image with this edited code?

Comment: For validate the upload I need control if the default image is not ic_launcher.png. If the image is ic_launcher.png not validate the upload else validate the upload.

Comment: yes. It is true. but by this drawable comparison, Is it going in if clause or else clause? This comparison is working or not?

Comment: Not working, because with ic_launcher the upload is validate.

Comment: Your default image is surely you are getting for R.drawable.ic_launcher ?? If it is so, then it should work. Check out your default image once.

Comment: Please read my question. At first I have posted the xml code of imageview

Answer (score 0):

Please try this tutorial, here's how you compare 2 Drawable objects in Android (Java): http://thoughtsoframy.blogspot.it/2013/08/comparing-drawables-in-android.html